# How to use bottlenose Python library with MWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws, bottlenose

For MWS requests, what credentials should I provide to bottlenose to access the Amazon Product Advertising API?

From the documentation, `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, and `AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG` appear to be required.

I am assuming that AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG is from Product Advertising API, do we have to get the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID from Product Advertising too?

Or can I use the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID that I got from MWS (Seller Centra) And provide the AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG from Product Advertising API?

more info: https://github.com/lionheart/bottlenose/issues/66

Comment: @Dan Loewenherz thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 0):

If you have `AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG` this. For secret and access. Goto IAM and for that user generate or get SECRET and access key.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you right, I know for sure MWS provides AWS access keys + secret, do you mean that the credentials need to be generated from IAM instead?